# Converting "Monday" to "Mon", "Tuesday" to "Tue", etc. in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am drawing a blank on how to change the Day of the Week column (DOW), from Monday to Mon, Tuesday to Tue, and so on.

```
DF = m
Column = DOW
```

ex:

```
DOW  
Monday  
Wednesday  
Friday
```

to

```
DOW  
Mon  
Wed  
Fri
```

I bet it's an easy fix, I have Googled, and found %a, but I am new and couldn't figure out the way to properly place it!

I've tried: m.DOW = m.DOW.strftime("%a")  and others, but that was the most recent.

Comment: `df['DOW'] = df['DOW'].str[:3]`?

Comment: I get an error because of 'DOW'. Unsure what is causing that.

Comment: According to your example the column is named `DOW`. What is the output of `df.head().to_dict()`

Comment: OMG!!! Thanks for showing me that code.... Turns out it was " DOW" causing the issue. I tried to check that by highlighting it and it wasn't showing a space. You are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `strftime()`. You can simply use the built in `str` method/property, and then use string slicing to get the first 3 letters of each day:

```
df['DOW'] = df['DOW'].str[:3]
```